# How can I add objects into an array without using push method in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I am trying to add object into an array.

Here is the code.

```
const output = { 201911: {15: {...}}, 201912: {10:{...}} } 
const keys = Object.keys(output) // ['201911', 201912']

let arr = []

keys.map((item, index) => arr.push({[keys[index]]: output[item]})) // [ {201911:{...}, {201912:{...}]
```

I can easily add objects into an array using push method but I am afraid this might causing an issue in a future and also I do not want to mutate array directly using push, shift or unshift methods etc...

Is there a safer way to add objects into an array?

Comment: If you don't want to mutate the array, how are you expecting to be able to add objects to that array? Seems impossible

Comment: millions of developers in hundreds of millions of projects used use now and will use `push` but you worry about it)

Comment: Use the return value of `.map()` instead of pushing: `let arr = keys.map((item, index) => ({[keys[index]]: output[item]}));`

Comment: Why did you worry about mutating an new created empty array?

Comment: I learned that push, pop, shift, unshift methods mutates an array directly and it might cause a side effect. So It is better to use method that creates new array such as map, splice, filter instead. This is why I did not want to use push method. Let me know if I need a correction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is use the `.map()` function the way it was intended:

```
const output = { 201911: {15: {...}}, 201912: {10:{...}} };
const keys = Object.keys(output);

let arr = keys.map((item, index) => 
  ({[keys[index]]: output[item]})
);
```

The `.map()` function is used when you want to apply a function to each element of a *source* array and use the returned value as an element of a *new* array. Because the whole point of `.map()` is to make a new array from the elements of an existing array, there's no need for your code to manipulate the new array at all.

There's nothing wrong with `.push()` otherwise; your concerns are unfounded.

Answer (score -2):

> I do not want to mutate array directly using push, shift or unshift methods etc...

You could destructure the array into a new array that contains the added element as well.

```js
const output = { 201911: {15: {}}, 201912: {10:{}} } 
const keys = Object.keys(output);

let arr = [];

console.log(arr);

arr = keys.reduce((res, item, index) =>  [...res, {[keys[index]]: output[item]}], arr);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: But this creates a completely new array on each iteration. It is an n-squared solution.

Comment: @Pointy yea... so?

Comment: Well why would you use an n-squared algorithm when a simple linear `.map()` call would suffice?

Comment: Because simply mapping over the keys in OP:s questions would override the array... not add to it. In other words, a simple `Array#map` is not equivalent to `Array#push`.

Comment: But the array is a *brand new array* with nothing in it before the operation starts. That's exactly the point of `.map()`.

Comment: In the example it is, yes. But the title of the question states `How can I add objects into an array`, not "how can i replace an array with new contents". Its a slight distinction, but an important one.